# Show that a l-homogenous polynomial is harmonic under certain conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}^d$ and $l \in \{2,3\}$. Then $P:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{C}, P(x):=(<a,x>+i<b,x>)^l$ is a $l$-homogenous polynomial. Show that $P$ is harmonic iff $||a||=||b||$ and $<a,b>=0$.

My attempt was to calculate the Laplace of $P(x)$. So I wrote $P(x)=(\sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i+i \sum_{i=1}^d b_i x_i)^l$. I'm not sure if it's correct but I got:

$$\Delta P(x)=l(l-1)(\sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i+i b_i x_i)^{l-2}\sum_{i=1}^d (a_i +i  b_i)^2$$

Assuming $P$ is harmonic, then it's Laplace is $0$ and since $l$ and $l-1$ can't be $0$ by definition one or both of the other factors has to be $0$. But those are complex numbers (without the exponents) and so for them to be $0$ their real and imaginary part have to be $0$. So $\sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i=\sum_{i=1}^d b_i x_i=\sum_{i=1}^d a_i=\sum_{i=1}^d b_i=0$.

I'm not sure what to conclude from here on or how to show the reverse direction. Also please check my work so far as I think I made some mistake or false assumption. Thanks!

EDIT: I wrote the sums as one and corrected my mistake when I calculated the Laplace operator. Now the forwards direction seems to be done. But I still don't know how to prove the reverse direction.

Comment: Either the last factor is $0$, or the $(\cdots)^{l-2}$ term is always $0$ which is only possible if $a=b=0$ (do you see why?). So you should look at the last factor being $0$. You should also fix the last factor according to the suggestion below, then equate the real and imaginary parts of *that* with $0$.

Comment: I mixed up divergence and gradient while calculating the Laplace operator. Now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the last term in the Laplacian of P in your expression should be something like
$$\sum_{k=1}^d( a_k +i b_k)^2$$
i didn't do the exact calculation though.